# Azure SQL Data Migration Assistant (DMA) Error - Three or Four Part Names

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I'm using the MS Data Migration Assistant tool to move a SQL Server 2016 DB to Azure. I'm getting the following error on 80+ stored procedures:

> Queries or references using three- or four-part names not supported in Azure SQL Database. Three-part name format, [database_name].[schema_name].[object_name], is supported only when the database_name is the current database or the database_name is tempdb and the object_name starts with #.

All of these stored procedures are using the current database and referencing the current database name. For example, this instruction is causing the error:

```
DELETE FROM [STDR].[dbo].[report] WHERE [report_id] = @xid
```

and when I run the command:

```
SELECT DB_NAME();
```

I get:

```
STDR
```

Could this be an error in the DMA tool? It's preventing me from executing the migration. I'd rather not have to modify all of these procedures. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**1.Queries or references using three- or four-part names not supported in Azure SQL Database.**

It's not the error in the DMA tool. Cross database queries using three or four part names is not supported in Azure SQL Server.

[image]

You can read more in the official documentation:[Resolving Transact-SQL differences during migration to SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information)。

**2.Three-part name format, [database_name].[schema_name].[object_name], is supported only when the database_name is the current database or the database_name is tempdb and the object_name starts with #.**

About this question, I have an idea and I think you can try it. You can specify target Azure Database instance which has the same database name and the same schema objects with your on-premises SQL Server. Otherwise, when your SQL Server 2016 DB is migrated to Azure, the current database is not `[STDR]` and cause the error.

Reference: [Migrate on-premises SQL Server or SQL Server on Azure VMs to Azure SQL Database using the Data Migration Assistant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-2017)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the error message specifically says: "Three-part name format, [database_name].[schema_name].[object_name], is supported only when the database_name is the current database"

Comment: Hi @dweeb_plus_plus ,please see my update, I given your an idea you can try it. Waiting your result.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the four-part name or three-part name that is not compatible with Azure SQL Database. You can script all your programing objects and then change the three part name format to two-part name format (dbo.[NameOfTheObjet]) on the script using Find and Replace on a text editor like Notepad++, then run that script on your Azure SQL Database to migrate your programming objects.

After that you can use DMA only to migrate the schema and data of your tables.